# How to transform R dataframe to duplicate rows and divide values from one column between two rows?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A","B","F","G","B","B","A","G","G","F","A","A","A","B","F"),
                 code = c(1,2,2,3,3,1,2,2,1,1,3,2,2,1,1),
                 value =  c(100,50,100,100,50,50,100,100,100,50,50,100,100,50,100))
```

I want now to duplicate the number of rows, so the `ID` column gets duplicated, the `code` column would duplicate leaving one value the same and another would be +1 and the value `column` would be divided between two. So the dataframe would look like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A","B","B","F","F","G","G","B","B","B","B","A","A","G","G","G","G","F","F","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","F", "F"),
                 code = c(1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,3,4,1,2,2,3,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,4,2,3,2,3,1,2,1,2),
                 value =  c(100,50,50,25,100,50,100,50,50,25,50,25,100,50,100,50,100,50,50,25,50,25,100,50,100,50,50,25,100,50))
```

Comment: For `value` one should stay the same and the other be divided by two or all divided by two?

Comment: all divided by two, I made a mistake in typing

Comment: Ok, then use `transform(rbind(df1, transform(df1, code = code + 1)), value = value / 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rbind` and `transform`.

```
rbind(df1, transform(df1, code = code + 1, value = value / 2))
```

To get the desired order use:

```
rbind(df1, transform(df1, code = code + 1, value = value / 2))[
    matrix(seq_len(nrow(df1)*2L), 2L, byrow=TRUE),]
#   ID code value
#1   A    1   100
#16  A    2    50
#2   B    2    50
#17  B    3    25
#3   F    2   100
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(code = code + 1,
         value = value / 2) %>% 
  bind_rows(df1)
```

---

To get the (interleaved) expected output, you can arrange:

```r
df1 %>% 
  mutate(row_number = row_number(),
         code = code + 1,
         value = value / 2) %>% 
  bind_rows(df1 %>% mutate(row_number = row_number()), ., .id = "df") %>% 
  arrange(row_number, df) %>% 
  select(-c(df, row_number))

#    ID code value
# 1   A    1   100
# 2   A    2    50
# 3   B    2    50
# 4   B    3    25
# 5   F    2   100
# 6   F    3    50
# 7   G    3   100
# 8   G    4    50
# 9   B    3    50
# 10  B    4    25
# 11  B    1    50
# 12  B    2    25
# 13  A    2   100
# 14  A    3    50
# 15  G    2   100
# 16  G    3    50
# 17  G    1   100
# 18  G    2    50
# 19  F    1    50
# 20  F    2    25
# 21  A    3    50
# 22  A    4    25
# 23  A    2   100
# 24  A    3    50
# 25  A    2   100
# 26  A    3    50
# 27  B    1    50
# 28  B    2    25
# 29  F    1   100
# 30  F    2    50
```